# setBackgroundColor(int) doesn't work on view in recycler. setBackgroundResource() does work

Tags: android, colors, setbackground

I have a recycler view which contains a list of classes for a particular day. Each class has a particular color associated with it. This color is shown in a view at the side of each CardView-

```
        <View
            android:id="@+id/colourBar"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />
```

In my recycler adapter I call `holder.colourBar.setBackgroundColor()`

However, this has no effect. The int values being passed are definitely valid, even if I just pass my apps primary color to all of them, it still doesn't show.
However, calling `holder.colourBar.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryLight);`
does work and sets the background colors of the view.

Why is it that passing an integer color value doesn't result in the color showing up?

Answer (score 0):

The input for `setBackgroundColor(int)` is different than `setBackgroundResource(int)`.

If you want to use a resource, like `R.color.colorPrimaryLight`, then you should use `setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryLight)`. The equivalent with `setBackgroundColor(int)` would be:

```
setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
```

A valid use of `setBackgroundColor(int)` would be something like `setBackgroudColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"))`, but using resources as much as possible is a best practice.

Answer (score 0):

`R.color.colorPrimaryLight`  is a resource not a color if you want to use in `setBackgroundColor()` you have to call the method `getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight)`

like this

```
holder.colourBar.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryLight))
```